# JPA No qualifying bean of type [javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory] is defined

Tags: spring, jpa

I have a JPA/spring/hibernate application deployed on Tomcat 8. But when the tomcat server startup i can see this warning message "No qualifying bean of type [javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory] is defined". Help would be appreciated because i have no idea about the configuration error.

persistence.xml

```
<persistence-unit name="persistenceUnit"
    transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
...
```

spring context files are defined into several files for reusability

context-ds.xml

```
<bean id="entityManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="datasource" />
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="persistenceUnit" />
</bean>
<bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManager" />
</bean>
<bean id="datasource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" >
...
```

context-config.xml

```
<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.app" />
<jpa:repositories base-package="com.app" />
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager"
    order="200" />
```

and web.xml

```
<context-param>
  <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
  <param-value>/WEB-INF/context-config.xml, /WEB-INF/context-ds.xml, /WEB-INF/context-dao.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

and DAO abstract class defines the PersistenceContext annotation

```
@PersistenceContext
protected EntityManager entityManager;
```

Real message

```
11:45:18.710 [localhost-startStop-1] WARN  AbstractBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryBean - Bean creation exception on FactoryBean type check: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'myDAO' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/context-dao.xml]: Cannot create inner bean 'genericDao$child#632cb33' of type [com.app.dao.GenericDaoImpl] while setting bean property 'target'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'genericDao$child#632cb33': Injection of persistence dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory] is defined
```

if i declare PersistenceContext like this, i have the message No bean named 'persistenceUnit' is defined

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName="persistenceUnit")
protected EntityManager entityManager;
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to define in an @Configuration annotated class a bean like this...  a nd name it accordingly to your ref

```
@Bean
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {

    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory = null;
    try {
        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        vendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(true);
        vendorAdapter.setShowSql(true);

        vendorAdapter.setDatabasePlatform(MyAppSettings.getDbPlattform());

        HibernateJpaDialect jpd = new HibernateJpaDialect();
        factory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();

        factory.setJpaDialect(jpd);
        factory.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        factory.setPackagesToScan(MyAppSettings.packagesToScan);
        factory.setDataSource(MyDataSource());

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return factory;
}
```

edit:

maybe your spring config xml isnt included into component scan
try :

```
@ImportResource("classpath:spring-config.xml")
```

....please post the full stacjtrace of you eception..

Comment: No the only reference to the LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean class is  in config-ds.xml which is the same configuration than yours

Comment: <bean id="entityManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
       <property name="dataSource" ref="datasource" />
      <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="persistenceUnit" />
    </bean>

Comment: Others parameters are specified in persistence.xml file (provider, jar to scan and properties).

Comment: It's a warning message but the application doesn't start. I modified the question to include it. Thanks.

Comment: What is the scope of component-scan when we use multiple spring configuration files?